# awk syntax error

Tags: awk

I get this syntax error with my code - I've tried putting the quotes in various places but no luck. Can someone please assist. Thanks!

```
awk: non-terminated string  | grep Re... at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<< 
awk: giving up
 source line number 2
```

```
awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / { split($5, addr, /:/); 
cmd = "/bin/geoiplookup " addr[1] | grep 'Rev 1:' | sed 's/Rev 1: //g' " | awk -F', ' '{print $4",", $3",", $2}'; 
cmd | getline rslt; 
close(cmd); 
print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, rslt }' < "$IP_PARSED" >> "$BlockedIPs"
```

Comment: Can you add code formatting and line-break that super-long line? I started but the quote nesting level makes it non-obvious what should be new-lined where for legibility...

Comment: is that better? I'm not sure how to do formatting on this site...

Comment: Significantly better, I just added a bit more tweaking to get the code to display as monospaced text that respects your line breaks. You can see what I did by clicking the time "ago" immediately next to the _edited_ text.

Comment: Score one for Perl's "choose your own single-quote (or double-quote)" mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we've been here before. Don't try to do complex processing inside the `cmd`. Use it to run your external command, then do the processing inside the main AWK program.

```
awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / { split($5, addr, /:/); 
cmd = "/bin/geoiplookup " addr[1] ; 
while (cmd | getline rslt) {
    if (rslt ~ /Rev 1: /) {
        gsub(/Rev 1: /, "", rslt)
        split(rslt, r, ",")
    }
}
close(cmd); 
print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, r[4], r[3], r[2] }' < "$IP_PARSED" >> "$BlockedIPs"
```

Comment: Hey Dennis, I get this new error message with you modified code

Comment: awk: newline in regular expression Rev 1:) {)... at source line 5
 context is
     if (rslt ~ /Rev 1:) { >>> 
 <<< 
awk: syntax error in regular expression Rev 1:) { at  {
 source line number 4

Comment: @Jim: Oh, there's a missing slash in the `if` statement.

Comment: weired ..I ran it again without making any changes and it worked this time .. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `awk` isn't terminated.  `awk` is interpreting the rest of your pipeline and getting confused.  If you actually intend for the pipeline to be part of your awk script, consider either writing your `awk` script as a file (removing the enclosing single quotes) or replace your outermost single quotes with double quotes and use `\` to escape intervening double quotes.  Unfortunately, you cannot nest single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to embed single quotes inside of single quotes.  This does not work; moreover, the shell provides no way to easily embed them.  There are some complex ways, for example

```
$ echo 'hello'"'"'world'
hello'world
$ echo 'hello'\''world'
hello'world
```

Note:  embedding `\'` does *not* work, as the equivalent does with double quotes.

```
$ echo 'hello\'world'
hello\'world
```

Comment: You're right that you can't use backslash-quote to directly embed a single quote in a single-quoted string, but embedding `\'` works if you terminate the single-quoted string first, and resume afterwards, so you actually type `'\''`, as in `echo 'hello'\''world'`.